# Eliminate temp file usage from shell script that extracts patterns from a file

Tags: shell

I have an input text file:

```
EL.EEX.FRANCE.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.VOL      15JAN2016
EL.EEX.GERMANY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.L       15JAN2016 
EL.EEX.GERMANY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.H       15JAN2016
EL.EEX.GERMANY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.S       15JAN2016 
EL.EEX.ITALY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.FWD            15JAN2016 
EL.EEX.ITALY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.FWD            15JAN2016
```

Given the sample data upto the max level of dot(.) we need unique type of 1 representative sample(complete line) without dates. So the output will be

```
EL.EEX.FRANCE.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.VOL
EL.EEX.GERMANY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.SPOT.L
EL.EEX.ITALY.DELMONTHS.JAN2016.FWD
```

(The order of the lines in the output doesn't matter.)

Below program works fine but it generates many intermediate temp files. How could we do without that in shell?

```
#input file name and path assumed in current directory
file="./osc.txt"
resultfilepath="./OSCoutput.txt"
tmpfilepath="./OSCtempoutput.txt"
tmp1filepath="./OSCtemp1output.txt"
tmp2filepath="./OSCtemp2output.txt"


rm $resultfilepath
rm $tmpfilepath
#using awk to filter only series data without dates
awk -F' ' '{print $1}' $file >> $tmpfilepath

#getting all the unique dataclass_names at column 1
DATACLASSNAME=(`cut -f 1 -d'.' $tmpfilepath | sort | uniq`)
for i in "${DATACLASSNAME[@]}"; do
rm $tmp1filepath
#we are filtering the file with that dataclass
awk -F'.' -v awk_dataclassname="$i" '$1==awk_dataclassname' $tmpfilepath >> $tmp1filepath
#also we are calculating the number of delimeter in filtered record and sorting it
COLCOUNT=(`awk -F'.' '{print NF}' $tmp1filepath | uniq | sort`)
for j in "${COLCOUNT[@]}"; do
rm $tmp2filepath
#in the filtered data we are taking series of a particular dimension length and dumping data
awk -F '.' -v awk_colcount="$j" '(NF==awk_colcount){print}' $tmp1filepath >> $tmp2filepath
#reducing column no by 1
newj=$(echo $((j - 1)))
#removing last column(generally observation dimension) by cut column
GREPSAMPLE=(`cut -f -$newj -d'.' $tmp2filepath | uniq`)
SAMPLELENGTH=(`wc -l $tmp2filepath`)
#we are now taking unique series sample
for k in "${GREPSAMPLE[@]}"; do
#doing grep of unique sample but taking the whole line
echo `grep $k $tmp1filepath | head -1` >> $resultfilepath

done
done
done
cat $resultfilepath
echo "processing finish"
```

Comment: If it works and does not take too long - what is the problem?

Comment: no order doesn't matter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole thing can be accomplished with just this `awk` invocation.

```
awk '{
    key = $0;
    sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", key);      # Let key be everything up to the last dot

    if (!seen[key]) { print $1 }    # If key has not been seen, print 1st col
    seen[key] = 1;                  # Mark the key as seen
}' "$file" > "$resultfilepath"
```

In general, when you have a script that involves lots of awking and grepping, chances are that you can just write an awk script.

Comment: Can be reduced to the "famous" awk idiom `awk -F. '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]++' file`

Comment: @glennjackman That won't work, because the hierarchy depth is not constant. Also, we want just the first column in the output.

Comment: Right. Then `awk -F. '{line = $0; NF --} !seen[$0]++ {print line}'`. And I read the requirements as "presentative sample(complete line)"